# SMS link queries

Tags: html, iphone, windows-phone, sms

I've been building a website for a local hobby group with a simple link system for sending SMS messages in bulk. It reads numbers from a database and then creates a HTML link depending on whether the user is on iPhone or not, in the format:

```
<a href="sms:111111;222222;333333&body=Message">iPhone Message Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="sms:111111;222222;333333?body=Message">Standard Message Link</a>
```

I personally have an Android device and can confirm that the standard link works perfectly for me, so long as the message is rawurlencoded first.

However, I couldn't find much useful documentation online about iPhone behaviour. I know that the ampersand is required rather than the question mark for body text, but I don't know whether the semicolon is correct for splitting numbers in the mailing list (some sites seem to suggest a comma).

I could also find no information about what format to use if my end user is on a Windows Phone.

I know that these links aren't universally supported by every device, but any help with formats that have worked for others would be appreciated.

Comment: [iOS docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html). Basically, `sms:62353535` should be safe. Not sure if there's such a URI for a Windows Phone though.  Have you considered sending out these mass SMS messages using an external service like [Nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/) instead?

Comment: Any external service costs money, and this is more of an "icing on the cake" feature for group admins to quickly get in touch with members, without having to keep phone contact lists up to date.

As far as the link, I'm sure that sms: followed by a single number will work on almost all modern devices, but the multiple recipient syntax is what I need. My example does the job on (some) Androids. The body variable is not really _needed_ (I use it to add a default header to the SMS so it's identifiable as a group message). I can happily drop the body variable for any OS that doesn't support it.

Comment: It's on Ask Different, but [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/34118) seems to suggest it might not be possible on iOS.